# Update integers (or numbers) by difference in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

Does EntityFramework Core provide a way to create an update query in such way, it will create an UPDATE that calculates the change of an numeric column instead of an absolute value?

**Context about the question**
Consider the following DbContext:

```
public class MyValue {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public int Value {get;set;}
}

public class MyContext : DbContext {
 public DbSet<MyValue> Values {get;set;}
}
```

A simple command could do the following:

```
var newValue = new MyValue { Value = 1 };
_dbContext.Add(newValue);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();

var value = _dbContext.Values.First();
value = value + 5;
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The resulting statement that'll be send to the database during `SaveChanges()`
Will be something like this:

> UPDATE SET [Value] = 6 WHERE ID = 1

But I'd like it to formulate an update statement like this:

> UPDATE SET [Value] = [Value] + 5 WHERE ID = 1

**WHY?**
If an update would be created like the second one, it'd not be neccesary for me to take precautions about concurrency. The database should be able to handle that for me.

I am aware, that I could create an StoredProcedure handling the update that way, but that seems not neccesary, if EFCore would just split the Update commands, making (all) numeric columns update by difference.
So - is there an integrated way to do that, or is there a feasible way to implement it during SaveChanges()?

Comment: I think you better implement [optimistic concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency). You can't do updates like that with EF.

Comment: Nah - optimistic locking and retrying until succeeding is too cumbersome in this example. Take the question as academic interest.